# Getting Invoke-WebRequest : Forbidden when doing a POST request using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I tried to send a POST request using powershell to get data from a page doing the following script :

```
$searchPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx"
$searchForm = $searchPage.Forms[0]
$searchForm.Fields.ctl00_ctl19_g_7591ec74_3f19_4144_8b7f_884234b48fc8_ctl00_txtNombreAdult = "1"
$searchForm.Fields.ctl00_ctl19_g_7591ec74_3f19_4144_8b7f_884234b48fc8_ctl00_txtNombreEnfants = "0"
$searchForm.Fields.ctl00_ctl19_g_7591ec74_3f19_4144_8b7f_884234b48fc8_ctl00_dtcDepart_dtcDepartDate = "19/01/2017"
$searchPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx" -Method POST -Body $searchForm.Fields
```

But I get this error :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx on this server.
At C:\Users\abdelouhabe\Desktop\Oncf2.ps1:56 char:19
+ $searchPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I've even filled the all other fields in the form too, but I'm still getting the same error.
Also, I tried to send the POST request using Postman google chrome extension and I got this error:

```
403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx on this server.
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I cant get to the site @ work because its blocked, but, its aspx. Sure there isnt a viewstate you have to submit too? Did you grab the headers from fiddler?

Comment: No I didn't do that. Even it's aspx, I inspected the page, there is a viewstate. how can the fiddler help?

Comment: I tried to send the POST request using Postman google chrome extension and I got this error  **403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx
on this server.**